# Understanding SQL Server behaviour with min(datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server

(long story short, was just a dumb assumption by me, I was sure a column was a datetime and it wasn't - so don't expect to find anything interesting in this question, leaving it here so that dems gets his rightfully accepted answer)

I wrote a simple query like this:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DateMadeActive) AS DateMadeActive
FROM RecordStateField WHERE RecordStatusID in (2, 3)
GROUP BY ID
```

Where DateMadeActive is a datetime column. This returned what I expected:

```
ID  DateMadeActive
1   20/06/2011 16:15:04
2   20/06/2011 16:14:28
```

Now I inserted this into a new table, but inserting the result of MIN(DateMadeActive) into a datetime column of another table gave me this error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

So to test this I change my select to this:

```
SELECT ID, CAST(Min(DateMadeActive) as datetime) AS DateMadeActive
FROM RecordStateField WHERE RecordStatusID in (2, 3)
GROUP BY ID
```

Same exception. I can write it like this and make it work:

```
SELECT ID, CONVERT(datetime, Min(DateMadeActive), 103) AS DateMadeActive
FROM RecordStateField WHERE RecordStatusID in (2, 3)
GROUP BY ID
```

So I can get it working, but this confuses me. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for MIN(expression) says the return type should be the same as expression, but what seems to be happening is that MIN(datetime) is returning nvarchar(255). I can confirm this by running this:

```
SELECT ID, Min(DateMadeActive) AS DateMadeActive
INTO TestTable
FROM RecordStateField WHERE RecordStatusID in (2, 3)
GROUP BY ID
```

And I can see that the DateMadeActive column is of type nvarchar(255). Anyone shed any light on this? Just a documentation bug in MSDN?

Comment: Could you post the definitions for the two tables?

Comment: Is it possible that you have `datetime2` column in one table and `datetime` in the second?

Comment: First question, are you sure that DateMadeActive is datetime?

Comment: What about `SELECT ID, DateMadeActive
INTO IsThisReallyDateTime
FROM RecordStateField WHERE 1=0`

Comment: It just turns out I was being an idiot and DateMadeActive is a nvarchar field. Which makes no sense schema wise, but what are you going to do. I just assumed it was a datetime as it makes so much more sense.

Comment: maybe add an edit at the top now you've identified your, er, issue

Comment: Oh yeah, I have prefixed the whole question with a disclaimer that there is nothing interesting to be found within!

Comment: Always something to be learned from eating humble pie. "Assumption is the mother of all -ups". :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me that `DateMadeActive` in `[RecordStateField]` is a VARCHAR(255) field.  Could you post the table definitions?

I ask this because MIN() has neve rchanged the type for me before.  And so if the result is a VARCHAR(255) it seems the input must also be a VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Gar, it's true, you're right, I was being an idiot. For some reason I assumed that DateMadeActive was a datetime column as it makes no sense for it to be a nvarchar(255) column.

Comment: (will accept your answer as soon as I can, apparently there is a time limit on accepting answers now?)