# SQL Server Scope_Identity() Usage Problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, scope-identity

I can't figure out why this multi-table insert (stored procedure) using scope_identity() is not working.  This is the gist of it (forgive the unimaginative naming here, please):

[image]

TableB's RowID column is obviously an int, not set as identity auto-increment or anything like that.

If I run it in management studio, it says 1 row was affected, but it does not do the inserts.

If I run it from code I get an error saying that I can't insert a NULL value in TableB, RowID, which is correct, it has a not null constraint.  But it should be getting the scope_identity() from the first table.

I've tried it in and out of transactions and with various parameter initializations... It's killing me.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume tableA has an IDENTITY set on a number column?

SCOPE_IDENTITY() will be NULL if there isn't

The "1 row affected" isn't from this INSERT into tableA either.

Comment: The TableA Primary Key is an auto-incrementing int.  Sorry for leaving that part out.  I've read that the scope_identity's numeric result can be assigned to an int parameter.

Comment: @theog: script the table, add to your question please. Add check this where the question was sure of datatypes... http://stackoverflow.com/q/6414700/27535

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code you have showed here. I think you have removed the problematic code when you simplified your sample.

Try this.

```
declare @TableA table (IDA int identity primary key, ColA int)
declare @TableB table (IDB int primary key, ColB int)

declare @RecordID int = 0,
        @Val1 int
        
if @RecordID = 0
  begin
    declare @NewID int

    insert into @TableA values (@Val1)
    set @NewID = scope_identity()

    insert into @TableB values (@NewID, @Val1)
  end
else
  begin
    print 'Do something else'
  end  

select *
from @TableA, @TableB
```

Result:

```
IDA         ColA        IDB         ColB
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           NULL        1           NULL
```

Take it for a spin yourself. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/103697/using-scope-identity

Comment: Well, hell's bells, even if this doesn't pinpoint my issue, finding out about the little stackexchange data analyzer tool is worth it!  I didn't know that was there--very cool.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to look at is whether you have a trigger (especially an INSTEAD OF Trigger)on the table which might be causing the record to not get inserted.

You can add a print statement to see the value of the @newId variable after you have initialized it to see if it is null or if it has a value.

Try using explicit transactions and a try catch block and then you can see what error you are getting in the catch block if it doesn't make it past the first insert.

Comment: I did look for triggers, but good point.  Also a good idea on the print statement for troubleshooting.  Thanks!